# how can I enable "higher elevation" in windows 7?

Tags: find

each time I try to save a file from Open Office or any program like it, I get requires higher elevation. I have tried to search for the file but nothing comes up and I not knowledgeable enough to know how to activate this function. I really need a step by step simple explanation of how to find it and activate it--from what I have read it has something to do with Vista? I am using windows 7 pro 64 bit and IE 11 on an acer laptop. Sure hope someone can help me out or even recommend a reputable alternative to Open office I can download where this feature doesn't come into play.

Comment: You might want to add administrator privileges to your user account navigate to: 'Control Panel\User Accounts and Family Safety\User Accounts\Change Your Account Type'.  Set it to administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You can start any program in administrator mode.
Right click on it and select run as administrator. That is the higher elevation in windows 7.

Comment: It depends on *where* you try to save the file; Windows OS requires permission to save files in the *Program Files* and *Program Files (x86)* directories, for example. You should not have any trouble saving them to *My Documents*, though. This is **not** an issue with Open Office, but a Windows security feature.

Comment: Save permissions may also depend on domain security policies, if that's the case.